# How to load balance azure website

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible (and how) to load balance Azure web sites?

Situation is that I have a web site which I deployed to few redundant nodes. Now I would like to set up load balancing for reliability purposes.

I see that load balancing is done using Traffic Manager service which I tried to use, however Traffic Manager doesn't allow me to add a web site endpoint. It only allows me to add a custom virtual machine I have. On a side note, web sites are running in standard mode which means each runs on it's own VM which led me to believe I could load balance them.

I see people create separate VMs with Windows Server and use IIS ARR to perform actual web request load balancing. Is there a way in Azure to load balance web sites directly?

Answer (score 4):

While converting over to web roles can very well suit your needs, an easier alternative may be to simply promote the web site up to the 'standard' tier, then increase the instance count. Windows Azure will then automatically handle load balancing the instances and even help ensure session affinity (which web roles can't do unless you jump through additional hoops).

Comment: This I did see, but afaik it's not possible to disperse those instances to different data centers. Am I wrong? This is a prompt Azure displays when adding another node: "_Increasing this site's Standard instances also increases instances of other Standard mode web sites in this region._"

Comment: today, no one of our service automatically scale across datacenters. That is the purpose of traffic manager. And currently, traffic manager only supports Cloud Services (both IaaS and PaaS). However, if the goal is just to add more capacity within a given datacenter, all three solutions (IaaS, PaaS, and Web Sites), support this model.

Comment: My goal was to have highly available website. Website service of West Europe data center had long outages last two days (most of the time this wasn't reported on `windowsazurestatus.com`). It was a bit embarrassing during a demo, so I wanted to exercise failover strategy. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I just checked and there were some partial service disruptions reported in the West EU region: http://www.windowsazurestatus.com/Rss/WSWE. If your site didn't meet its SLA, be sure to report it (support ticket) so you can receive proper billing credit. If failover is what you're after, then traffic manager may be a good fit. Just make sure you have a strategy for any data replication needs. :)

Comment: I'm still pondering the switch to Azure. If you bump up the number of instances, it still runs under a single instance until traffic deems in necessary to run under more, correct?

Comment: no, if you increase the number of instances, it automatically scales out. however, there are also options in place to create "auto-scaling rules" so that the system can automatically scale up/down based on parameters you set.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make your sites use Web Roles?

This only requires a very small change to the project to add a startup class.

These are automatically load balanced. 
You are required to have at least two role instances to trigger the SLA.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but can you point me to a tutorial about load balancing aspect of web roles? Frankly, I'm quite new to Azure and didn't even know about web roles. I've found [a tutorial series](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-1-overview/) about web roles, but I'll need some time to read through them. I see that they require web app to have tight integration with Azure which isn't very nice. Are you aware of some limitations of web roles? Thanks!

Comment: I found [a nice article describing pros and cons of using web sites, web roles and VMs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/). Web roles provide Traffic Manager support, but also take a way several very useful features (such as git, ftp and web deploy, instant deployment and configuration sharing). Thanks for pointing me to web roles. I'll accept the answer for pointing me to them.

Comment: Web roles don't require that much custom code to change between the two. The only key difference is the WebRole class which is ignored if you chose to treat it as a web application. You have the option to use more of Azure but is not forced. To show this start up visual studio and create a new cloud project with a web role that is a simple asp.net application. If you set the application as the startup project you will not know that Azure is in use. If the cloud project is run localy then it will run in the emulator.

Comment: Web roles do take away some options but do give others. The ability to switch a deployment between prod and staging is very powerful.

Comment: Web Sites now have a staging/production capability as well. :) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance.aspx

Comment: Web roles across data centers are NOT automatically load balanced! Plus deploying Web Roles (a.k.a. Cloud Service) in different data centers does not make your job easier either! Now you have to maintain  two (or more) separate deployments and take care of the updates!

Comment: I did not say that they are load balanced across data centers.